# How to dynamically set the domain for ssl_certificate

Tags: docker, nginx, lua, openresty

I am using lua via openresty and setting an environmental variable to dynamically set the domain name. I have:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

env MYDOMAIN;

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        set_by_lua $MYDOMAIN 'return os.getenv("MYDOMAIN")';
        server_name $MYDOMAIN www.$MYDOMAIN;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
          index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$MYDOMAIN/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$MYDOMAIN/privkey.pem;    
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/$MYDOMAIN/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/$MYDOMAIN/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

Setting server_name works fine but in the case of ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key it is taking the value of $MYDOMAIN literally.

Comment: is your ssl certificate is valid? i mean it's been updated

Comment: Yes it is valid. If I hardcore the value it works.

Comment: Why not use `ssl_certificate_by_lua_block ` https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/ssl.md ?

Comment: Since version 1.15.9 it is possible to use variables at file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every nginx directive allow embedded variables. `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` don't support it.

But you may use [ssl_certificate_by_lua_block](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ssl_certificate_by_lua_block) and [ngx.ssl](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/ssl.md)

The main workflow:

1. Specify any valid stub certificate within nginx config.
2. Follow [ngx.ssl synopsis](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/ssl.md#synopsis), it would need some certificate format conversions.
   Use `os.getenv("MYDOMAIN")` to build the file path to open and read the cert. files contents.
3. Cache converted keys to avoid file read and conversions for the same domain upon every request.

> You can always use libraries like lua-resty-lrucache and/or ngx_lua
>   APIs like lua_shared_dict to do the caching of the DER-formatted
>   results, for example.

Comment: can you provide an example? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: BTW, I would be selected nginx conf tempalting approach for your use case, because your configuration is static. `ssl_certificate_by_lua_block` is designed for dynamic cert selection, for example based on SNI.

Comment: Complete example of using ngx.ssl with caching may be a full page Lua code. If I l have enough free time I will write such example.

Answer (score 4):

Nginx version 1.15.9 support variables in "ssl_certificate" and "ssl_certificate_key" directives.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are not resolved in nginx config as you already know and not every directive supports variable.

I wrote a article long back on the same

https://tarunlalwani.com/post/simple-parameterized-config-files-docker/

The idea is to update your config file before running nginx. So you will have a startup script

```
#!/bin/bash

envsubst < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
exec nginx "-g" "daemon off;"
```

This will make things a lot easier. A tougher route would be to use `ssl_certificate_by_lua_block` to dynamically load the certificate.

https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/ssl.md

Answer (score 0):

From documentation: Since version 1.15.9, variables can be used in the file name when using OpenSSL 1.0.2 or higher

Example:

```
ssl_certificate     $ssl_server_name.crt;
ssl_certificate_key $ssl_server_name.key;
```